# How to get index of a struct using values

Tags: c++

```
struct prediction
{
   string  address;
    long int  index;
};
struct prediction *bp = new struct prediction[1300];    
bp[0].index =0;
bp[0].address =2553278;
bp[1].index =1;
bp[1].address =1356;
```

How can I get the index of bp based on the address i.e what is the index if address = 1356

Comment: What is the address that you're talking about? It doesn't seem to be memory addresses here. Also, you're trying to assign an int to a string in your code.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang he has a variable called `address`

Comment: @Aggragoth Yes, but what does it store? It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what the values of that variable actually mean.

Comment: I don't know, my guess its just not intrinsically thought out.

Comment: Unless there is some order to your data you can only perform exhaustive search. And even then you might get duplicates.

Comment: Your question is **very** unclear. Do you want to get the index value of the first element in bp that has an address equal to 1356?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::find_if` from the `algorithm` library:

```cpp
struct prediction *bp = new struct prediction[1300];    
bp[0].index =0;
bp[0].address =2553278;
bp[1].index =1;
bp[1].address =1356;
prediction* ptr_to_searched = std::find_if(bp, bp + 1300, [](const prediction& p) { return p.address == 1356;});
if( ptr_to_searched != bp + 1300 )
{
    size_t index = static_cast<size_t>(ptr_to_searched - bp);
}
else
{
 // Not found
}
```

Also, you should not use dynamic arrays through `new`. Use `std::vector` instead. Naked `new`s in your code are only a source for bugs (i.e. memory leaks).

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer (or iterator for that matter) returned by `find_if` without checking for the past-the-end iterator is dangerous. You invoke UB if `find_if` didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The index of the element at memory address `a` will be exactly:

```
std::distance(bp, a);
```

---

`std::find_if` can be used to find the memory address an element with a particular member value.

Comment: OP is probably talking about the member variable called address and not the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have properly assigned the `address` members with strings rather than integers, you can simply loop over the array and look for the one you want:

```cpp
std::string looking_for("1356");

for (int ndx = 0; ndx < 1300; ndx++)
{
    if (bp[ndx].address == looking_for)
        break;
}

std::cout << "the index is " << ndx << '\n';

if (ndx < 1300)
   std::cout << "bp[" << ndx << "].index is " << bp[ndx].index << '\n'
```